# R converting factor columns to character not functioning

Tags: r, type-conversion, character

I have a dataset like so:

```
> head(data3, n = 10)
   city company_name event_date                                                  name state street                                team_name
1                     5/14/2016                     Heart Walk 2015-2016 St. Louis MO                                          Team Clayton
2                     9/26/2015                       Heart Walk 2015-2016 Canton, OH    OH                               Cardiac Crusaders
3                     9/12/2015                       Heart Walk 2015-2016 Dallas, TX    TX                                BIS - Team Myers
4                      6/3/2017                  FDA HW 2016-2017 Albany, NY WO-65355                                   Independent Walkers
5                      5/6/2017               FDA HW 2016-2017 New Haven, CT WO-66497                                                      
6                    10/17/2015                  Heart Walk 2015-2016 Puget Sound, WA    WA            UB SEA/North: Arlington-Smokey Point
7                     9/17/2016                    Heart Walk 2016-2017 San Diego, CA                           MUFG ISA SD: Town Center Dr
8                     9/27/2015                     Heart Walk 2015-2016 Triangle, NC                    Fabulous Foster and the Pacemakers
9                     10/1/2016 Heart Walk 2016-2017 Gulf Coast (Gulfport-Biloxi), MS    MS                                Cardiac Division
10                    10/8/2016                Heart Walk 2016-2017 Pierce County, WA    WA        Brains &amp; Hearts- the Important Parts
```

These columns are part of a larger dataset. I am trying to convert them from factors to character strings using the following code:

```
chr_cols <- c("city", "company_name", "event_date", "name", "state", "street", "team_name")
data3 <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[chr_cols], as.character))
```

But this doesnt work:

```
> str(data3)
'data.frame':   196879 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ city        : Factor w/ 7310 levels "","Abbeville",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ company_name: Factor w/ 238 levels "","Aetna Overland Park, KS",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ event_date  : Factor w/ 190 levels "1/29/2017","10/1/2016",..: 107 181 159 135 121 9 167 183 2 30 ...
 $ name        : Factor w/ 910 levels "2014-2015 New York City Marathon",..: 606 391 422 18 23 566 807 619 727 794 ...
 $ state       : Factor w/ 58 levels "","AE","AK","AL",..: 1 40 50 1 1 54 1 1 29 54 ...
 $ street      : Factor w/ 120060 levels "",".","\"145 Saint Botolph Street, Unit 13\"",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ team_name   : Factor w/ 59509 levels "","_HEART_","_the brave hearts_",..: 45140 7622 5937 23443 1 55390 31645 15739 7629 6503 ...
```

What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: When you do `as.data.frame`, the `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`  So, it will change it to `factor` again.  Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or assign it to the columns of interest i.e. `data[chr_cols] <- lapply(data[chr_cols], as.character)`

Comment: Alternatively, use the tidyverse solution: ```as_data_frame```.

Comment: Lol. `stringsAsFactors` strikes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.frame` casts character vectors back into factors by default. Break that by supplying:

```
data3 <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[chr_cols], as.character), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but I had done `as.data.frame(lapply(data[chr_cols], as.character, stringsAsFactors=F))` so this fixed it